# Methods not found while upgrading from Vaadin7 to Vaadin8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-flow, vaadin8

Update from vaadin 7.7.6 to vaadin 8.20.0

I am trying to upgrade my project from vaadin7 to vaadin8. I am not able to find the alternatives for below method.

In my existing code, below methods has been used :

```
ContextMenuItem item;
item.setData(data);
item.getData();
```

But since ContextMenuItem has been removed from vaadin8 and MenuBar.MenuItem has been provided, I could not find any similar method.
I want to set data into the MenuItem, how this can be done? Are there any similar methods in import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.MenuItem;.

I want to achieve something like :

```
com.vaadin.contextmenu.MenuItem item;
item.setData(data);
item.getData()
```

TIA !

Comment: Why upgrade from an unsupported to yet another unsupported platform? Directly migrating to 23.x or 24.x will probably be more appropriate. (The 8->23 migration is not that different from 7->23 migration)

Comment: Hi @AndréSchild, I have such a requirement in my project where I have to update it to vaadin8 that's why I am looking for the alternatives for these methods.

Comment: @NewBee, if your company has license for Vaadin 8.20.3, you should have access to Vaadin's professiona support. Go to vaadin.com site and ask for more info by using the blue chat box on the bottom right corner.